# Advanced Search "Does Not Contains" your query is malformed

Tags: 2010, search, search-results, fast-search, exception

When I am using advanced search and  selecting the property from first dropdown and selecting "Does not equal" or "Does not contain" and clicking on search button, result is showing me that "Your Query is malformed. Please rephrase your query."

I am using Fast Search.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the fact that you haven't indexed content into the managed property yet. Also make sure the property is queryable.

Comment: Thanks @Mikael. I have found this [HOTFIX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849985). So i think it's a Known issue of fast. WDYS?

Comment: The hotfix is no longer available - check a later CU

Comment: So is there any other option to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the case when you return to many results - try to narrow down your search query, e.g limit it to a site scope. 
When fetching the results take too long, you get this error.

Comment: Hi @Max. I am already using a scope which is getting results from a list, Also i have found this [HOTFIX](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2849985). WDYS?